# Is there a way to use RODBC (or similar) to access a SECUREFX file (.xfr format) and import into R?

Tags: rodbc, microsoft-r

I currently have to manually open SECUREFX every day to pull an autodialer phone extract.. If I forget.. the old file is replaced with a new file every day.. If I miss a day.. I will lose that days data. I am trying to find a way to grab this file in R every morning when I come in and save it for when I need it later in the day.

I currently use the RODBC package to connect to a SQL server with code like:

```
con <- odbcConnect("ODBC connection name", uid = "rsource", pwd ="");

query <- "Select * FROM server.schema.Table"

inbound <- sqlQuery(con, query)
```

I can't find anything that mentions being able to do this (or something similar) with SECUREFX

Ultimate goal would be to connect to secureFX, import file, resave to my local machine.

Or is there a better way to automate that file transfer?
  I don't use secureFX for anything else ever.. I am very new to it (a few days) and could use any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.vandyke.com/support/automation/schedsfxcl.html?

Comment: Sorry for such a late response.. I have looked a little bit at their site.. not a ton.. I am bouncing between several projects right now and won't have time to really look at that until maybe Wednesday.. 

I will definitely poke around some more.